# Python add audio to video opencv

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, opencv, python

I use python cv2 module to join jpg frames into video, but I can't add audio to it. Is it possible to add audio to video in python without ffmpeg?
P.S. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Do you want to produce video (save) a video file or have an effect of video being played with accompanying music without creating a file? Those are two very different goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ffpyplayer to handle the audio part.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#ffpyplayer for playing audio
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
video_path="../L1/images/Godwin.mp4"
def PlayVideo(video_path):
    video=cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    player = MediaPlayer(video_path)
    while True:
        grabbed, frame=video.read()
        audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()
        if not grabbed:
            print("End of video")
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
        if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
            #audio
            img, t = audio_frame
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
PlayVideo(video_path)
```

The sample code will work but you need to play around the cv2.waitKey(28) depending on the speed of your video.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What am I supposed to do with `img` and `t`?

Comment: img is the image of the frame while t is the timestamp. I added them for someone who may need further processing. For more details check:  https://pypi.org/project/ffpyplayer/ or https://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/player.html

Comment: @DK250 The audio and video are not synchronized. In my case, the audio plays a bit later after the frame has passed.

Comment: @Raj increase the value in the waitKey(). I think your current value is small and the video is very fast.

Comment: Downvoted as the example doesn't result in video with audio. Also it ignores video frame rate. If I understand OP correctly, the input should be a list of jpeg files plus frame rate or video without sound (it already has a frame rate) and the result should be a file with audio, that can be played by a video player app such QuickTime or VLC or in browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am reading audio and video frames:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from pafy import pafy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video = pafy.new('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_IR90FthXQ')
    stream = video.getbest(preftype='mp4')

    video = VideoFileClip(stream.url)
    audio = video.audio
    for t, video_frame in video.iter_frames(with_times=True):
        audio_frame = audio.get_frame(t)
        print(audio_frame)
        print(video_frame)
```

This code downloads YouTube video and returns raw frames as numpy arrays.
You can pass the file as an argument to the VideoFileClip instead of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pygame for audio.
You need to initialize pygame.mixer module
And in the loop, add pygame.mixer.music.play()
But for that, you will need to choose audio file as well.

However, I have found better idea! You can use webbrowser module for playing videos (and because it would play on browser, you can hear sounds!)

import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("video.mp4")

Answer (score 0):

You can use moviepy library to do that. Behind the scenes, it uses ffmpeg to merge audio and video.

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

video_path = 'Path to video file'
audio_path = 'Path to audio file'
output_path = 'Path to output video+audio file'

video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_path)
audio = mp.AudioFileClip(audio_path)

video = video.set_audio(audio)

video.write_videofile(output_path)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(
    'c:Your_file')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while True:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick()
    #used to show that you can do other stuff while playing audio
    print("hi")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?